IBM Cognos Analytics version 11.1.7 or 11.2.2, Extract Lineage information of entire report with API calls
There are few Reports and Queries, I am able to access in IBM Cognos Analytics == 11.1.7 or 11.2.2,
Deployed On-Premise
There are a huge no of reports and queries for which I want to extract Lineage Information,
I want to automate extraction of Lineage information of entire report using API calls,
Please help in finding an API call which will help in extracting Lineage information of entire report,
Thanks in Advance.
I tried checking Lineage information for reports using UI,
Select data point in UI,
Get Expression used to show data point,
Navigate to table/column used in Data point,
Right click on column and click on Lineage
It took so much time taking to get Lineage Information of one page of a report manually,
I want to extract Lineage Information for multiple reports, few reports have multiple pages,
To extract lineage information for all reports, It would be easier to automate with API calls.

The following link to the documentation should get you started:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/12.0.0?topic=specifications-creating-lineage-requests-reports
Further into the documentation there is the an example:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/12.0.0?topic=reports-sample-request-xml-saved-report#request_rsvp_primary
